# How to verify cross platform installation steps

Tags: linux, unix, installation, cross-platform, hp-ux

I have to check installation steps of my application on different production machines. I want to check how can I install my application on **HP UX**. I have only linux/windows machines but dont have real physical HP unix machine. Is there any way i can check installation steps of HP unix. I am thinking of any virtual environment or any flavour that run on linux or windows which gives accessiblity and functionality of HP unix.

I am looking something to cross check platfrom installation steps.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.  HP-UX is as different from Linux as Linux is from Windows (almost).  There would be many differences in libraries, patches, installed utilities, build tools, etc.

A few examples:

1. HP-UX does not come pre-installed with the bash shell
2. HP-UX uses a proprietary software packager and installer called swinstall (analogous to RPM but completely different)
3. Partition layout is different
4. Many common utilities behave differently.  "echo" is one of many examples.  This will affect things if your build process uses shell utilities
5. Even if you can test the install, don't you need to test the product's operation on HP-UX?

Not saying it's impossible.  If your application uses basic, nonspecific utilities for install, it might work.  There is no way to know without a running installation.  Unfortunately you need Itanium hardware and the O/S.

My recommendation would be to get your application working on Solaris and any other Unixes first.  The more platforms you test on, the more portable your code will become on all of them.  Then, put out some feelers and find someone with a system you can borrow time on.

Worst case, find an Itanium server like an rx2620 on eBay, should not cost too much.  Even better if the seller forgets to wipe the O/S :).  You'll need a terminal and possibly null modem.  11.31 (11iv3) is the latest version of the O/S.